# How can I install gulp-cli#4.0?

Tags: npm, gulp, npm-install

I have trouble with installing gulp-cli.

```
npm install -g "gulpjs/gulp-cli#4.0"
```

I am getting this error.

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! Command failed: C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin\git.EXE checkout 4.0
npm ERR! error: pathspec '4.0' did not match any file(s) known to git.
npm ERR!
```

Sorry for this question but what I am doing wrong with this?

Comment: Where did you get this command from? The last version of gulp-cli in their repo is 1.4.0, so it's unlikely that you'll be able to install 4.0: https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp-cli/releases Also, gulp-cli doesn't seem to use namespaces so `npm install -g gulp-cli` should be enough to install the last version, or `npm install -g gulp-cli@1.4.0` (notice the `@` instead of the `#`) if you want to install a specific one.

Comment: This command was in my task. Toomorow I will know what I'm suppose to do.

Answer (score 0):

Guy the last version of gulp-cli is 2.0.1, to install a specific version just run `npm i -g gulp-cli@VERION-THAT-YOU-NEED` maybe you would like to install gulp that is on version 4.0.0-alpha.3 , for it just run: `npm install gulpjs/gulp#v4.0.0-alpha.3`